# Twisted: Using connectProtocol to connect endpoint cause memory leak?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, twisted

I was trying to build a server. Beside accept connection from clients as normal servers do, my server will connect other server as a client either.

I've set the protocol and endpoint like below:

```
p = FooProtocol()
client = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, '127.0.0.1' , 8080) # without ClientFactory
```

Then, after call `reactor.run()`, the server will listen/accept new socket connections. when new socket connections are made(in connectionMade), the server will call `connectProtocol(client, p)`, which acts like the pseudocode below:

```
while server accept new socket:
    connectProtocol(client, p)
    # client.client.connect(foo_client_factory)    --> connecting in this way won't
    #                                                  cause memory leak
```

As the connections to the client are made, the memory is gradually consumed(explicitly calling `gc` doesn't work).

Do I use the Twisted in a wrong way?

-----UPDATE-----

My test programe: Server waits clients to connect. When connection from client is made, server will create 50 connections to other server

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gc

from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, defer, endpoints
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol

class MyClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class MyClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        p = MyClientProtocol()
        return p

class ServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        p = ServerProtocol()
        return p

client_factory = MyClientFactory() # global
client_endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, '127.0.0.1' , 8080) # global

times = 0

class ServerProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        global client_factory
        global client_endpoint
        global times

        for i in range(50):
            # 1)
            p = MyClientProtocol()
            connectProtocol(client_endpoint, p) # cause memleak

            # 2)
            #client_endpoint.connect(client_factory) # no memleak

        times += 1
        if times % 10 == 9:
            print 'gc'
            gc.collect() # doesn't work

        self.transport.loseConnection()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_factory = ServerFactory()
    serverEndpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:8888")
    serverEndpoint.listen(server_factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug in Twisted, but you haven't attached enough code here to tell.  Can you attach a whole program?

Comment: Thanks to reply! A updates has been made with my test code.

Comment: There does indeed appear to be a leak here.  In fact, I get a leak with *both* examples, although it's a bit faster with the connectProtocol-based example.  This is definitely a bug in Twisted, and we will need to investigate.

Answer (score 4):

This program doesn't do any Twisted log initialization.  This means it runs with the "log beginner" for its entire run.  The log beginner records all log events it observes in a `LimitedHistoryLogObserver` (up to a configurable maximum).

The log beginner keeps 2 ** 16 (`_DEFAULT_BUFFER_MAXIMUM`) events and then begins throwing out old ones, presumably to avoid consuming all available memory if a program *never* configures another observer.

If you hack the Twisted source to set `_DEFAULT_BUFFER_MAXIMUM` to a smaller value - eg, 10 - then the program no longer "leaks".  Of course, it's really just an object leak and not a memory leak and it's bounded by the 2 ** 16 limit Twisted imposes.

However, `connectProtocol` creates a new factory each time it is called.   When each new factory is created, it logs a message.  And the application code generates a new `Logger` for each log message.  *And* the logging code puts the new `Logger` *into* the log message.  This means the memory cost of keeping those log messages around is quite noticable (compared to just leaking a short blob of text or even a dict with a few simple objects in it).

I'd say the code in Twisted is behaving just as intended ... but perhaps someone didn't think through the consequences of that behavior complete.

And, of course, if you configure your own log observer then the "log beginner" is taken out of the picture and there is no problem.  It does seem reasonable to expect that all serious programs will enable logging rather quickly and avoid this issue.  However, lots of short throw-away or example programs often don't ever initialize logging and rely on print instead, making them subject to this behavior.

**Note** This problem was reported in [#8164](http://tm.tl/8164) and fixed in [4acde626](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/commit/4acde6268c736a47a6f8203fbff46767214f0b2e) so Twisted 17 will not have this behavior.